# FFmpeg/avconv rotate video with watermark adding using PHP-FFmpeg

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, avconv

I've got problem with rotating video and adding watermark during the same request. My system can get video from mobile devices and has to reformat it for HTML5. so I'm making mp4,webm and ogv formats. Everything works fine, I've figured out how to get video rotation using Mediainfo. I have only one problem. When I want add watermark and rotation to video during the same request I've got only video with watermark (in proper resolution and format) but without rotation. I've read that it is possible to achieve using complex-filter. Has anyone expirience how to make it possible using PHP-ffmpeg? It is very simple to use library, and works for me so it would be really cool if it will start to work.

Comment: Are you using `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg, or `avconv`/countefeit "`ffmpeg`" from Libav? You should show your actual command(s). Do you really need a php-ffmpeg wrapper?

Comment: Ok I've found the solution working well with PHP-ffmpeg wrapper. The solution was building from sources ffmpeg according to manual which is available on ffmpeg website. After this operation everything is working like a charm :)

Comment: You can make an answer to this question now that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution working well with PHP-ffmpeg wrapper. The solution was building from sources ffmpeg according to manual which is available on ffmpeg website. After this operation everything is working like a charm :)